# why this will cause core dump or deadlock

Tags: c++, concurrency, c++17, mutex, deadlock

I am writing a code for implement thread-safe and thread-unsafe progrm for deadlock. If everything works well, the there is no problem running it.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include<vector>
#include <mutex>

using namespace std;

class Balance {
public:
    int num;

    explicit Balance(int num) : num(num) {};
    std::mutex m;
};


void transfer_unsafe(Balance &from, Balance &to, int n) {
    from.num -= n;
    to.num += n;
}


void transfer(Balance &from, Balance &to, int n) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock1(from.m, std::defer_lock);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock2(to.m, std::defer_lock);
    std::lock(from.m, to.m);
    from.num -= n;
    to.num += n;
}


int main() {


    auto test = [](const string &name, const auto func) {

        auto start_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        Balance a{100};
        Balance b{100};
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "before " << a.num << " " << b.num << std::endl;

        std::vector<std::thread> threads;

        threads.reserve(100);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            threads.push_back(std::thread{func, std::ref(a), std::ref(b), 1});
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            threads.push_back(std::thread{func, std::ref(b), std::ref(a), 1});
        }

        for (auto &t: threads) {
            t.join();
        }
        std::cout << "after " << a.num << " " << b.num << std::endl;
        auto end_time = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        std::cout << "time : " << (end_time - start_time).count() << std::endl;
    };

    test("unsafe", transfer_unsafe);
    test("safe", transfer);


}
```

but why it causes core dump ? does it have deadlock

I expect this program above to print out the 2 cases, but the `safe` part will not give any answer.

Comment: Are you running on Linux, compiling with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`, and able to use [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) on the dumped `core` file?

Comment: Trying to lock mutex twice in the same thread (like you do in `transfer`) is Undefined Behaviour - anything can happen.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Note that both `unique_lock`s in `transfer` are constructed specifying `std::defer_lock` -- so I don't think there's any double locking going on (unless I've missed something).

Comment: @G.M. You are right, didn't notice that. Still, it's UB because threads terminate without unlocking a mutex (locked with `std::lock`).

Comment: Data race of `test("unsafe", transfer_unsafe);` is UB...

Comment: Indeed, it should be `std::lock(lock1, lock2);`

Comment: @Yksisarvinen, the snippet is based on reference example: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock . The entire point of `std::unique_lock` is to unlock at scope exist. So your argument about thread termination does not hold.

Comment: @Red.Wave That only holds if the mutex is locked via the `unique_lock` managing it.  That's *not* the case in the OP's code.

Comment: @Red.Wave Yes, I believe that's what OP tried to achieve, but that only works if you pass `std::unique_lock` into `std::lock` call, not the underlying mutexes. See Jarod's comment.

Comment: @Jarod42  you are right.  it should be `std::lock(lock1, lock2);`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I used windows to compile, it shows no results. Then I used some online compiler, it said core dump